# Rsync exclude all files in dir except specific files

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to exlude all files of the directory cache/, except some specific files. Beside I want to Backup every other files in my source.

Content of source dir:

```
backup-test/
├── cache
│   ├── adodb
│   │   ├── .htaccess
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── test-adodb-1.html
│   │   ├── test-adodb-2.html
│   │   └── test-adodb-3.html
│   ├── .htaccess
│   ├── test-cache-1.html
│   ├── test-cache-2.html
│   └── test-cache-3.html
├── .htaccess
├── test-root-1.html
├── test-root-2.html
└── test-root-3.html
```

The files in `cache/` I want to backup and shouldn't be excluded:

```
cache/index.html
cache/adodb/.htaccess
```

My command:

```
rsync -av --delete \
--include "cache/index.html" \
--include "cache/adodb/.htaccess" \
--exclude "cache/*" \
-e ssh "$SSH_REMOTE":"$BACKUP_SOURCE" "$BACKUP_DEST"
```

Output:

```
receiving incremental file list
backup-test/
backup-test/.htaccess
backup-test/test-root-1.html
backup-test/test-root-2.html
backup-test/test-root-3.html
backup-test/cache/

sent 174 bytes  received 431 bytes  1,210.00 bytes/sec
total size is 35  speedup is 0.06
```

But it's not working as I expect. Rsync only backups an empty cache/ dir, without my included files.
What can I do?

Comment: Can you please share the command output as well so then it would be easy to find the issue.

Comment: @asnath I added the content of my source dir and the rsync output.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.I hope this help you to not spend that much time.

first you can create a file(include.txt) which you will used in include-from and in that you can add below lines & save it:

```
+ index.html
+ adodb*
+ adodb/.htaccess
- *
```

you can then use this rsync command to backup only include this files mentioned in include.txt and exclude everything:

> Blockquote

rsync -ruvv --rsh=ssh --include-from=include.txt   remoteSrv:/cache/    $BACKUP_DEST